# Left align text in right aligned cell

Tags: html, css

I have a `table` where all first columns are text aligned to right. Is there a possibilty to align only text to left where `td`'s align property is already right?

For better understanding:

[image: align preview]

**HTML:**

```
<table class='tcl'>
<tr>
<td>first column</td>
<td>second column</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tcl {
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
}

.tcl tr {

    height:50px;
}

.tcl td {

     width:50%;
     text-align:left;
}

.tcl td:first-child {

     text-align:right;
     /* i would like to align the text of this right aligned column to the left*/
}
```

**EDIT :** Many people dont really understand what i meant. Text-align not only moves text to the selected side of the parent, but does also change the way texts are aligned to each other.

So what i would like to achieve is this

```
   first   row
   second  row
   third   row
```

and not this

```
    first  row
   second  row
    third  row
```

So, the texts in first column are in both cases aligned to the right, but alignment of the text is left in first case, and right in second case. I hope this explains the thing.

Comment: It does, only that text in left column is right aligned. Like i said to the daniel, i want the text-left aligned on the right side of the column.

Comment: I am afraid you dont understand. The only problem here is first column. I want the whole thing to be on the right side, but i want the ALIGN of characters to be left (text start from the same point on the left side). Check the picture.

Comment: Are you not allowed to change the css or what? why aren't you removing the `text-align: right`?

Comment: @Mr_Green because otherwise it would move the text to the left side of the column. I dont want it to be moved to left, just text to be left aligned (start from the same point).

Comment: @Mr_Green He wants an effect similar to having a text-indent so that the column as far as possible to the right edge of the first column.

Comment: Really, this is going on top of me.. I hope you got the solution in below posts.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you happy to use padding to align the text?

Change;

```
text-align: right;
```

To;

```
padding-left: 35%;
```

...or similar value.

http://jsfiddle.net/seG2S/3/

You could use Javascript to determine how wide your column is, and update the padding.

Comment: Yes this is what i meant. Widths are fixed anyway so there is no need for javascript to check for changes.

Comment: @BikerJohn if that is what you want then that happens automatically if you don't add width. right? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seG2S/4/).

Comment: @BikerJohn does my solution not do this then?

Comment: @olimortimer it does. I just wanted to see what other solutions exist. :)

Comment: No probs @BikerJohn , just wanted to check :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by adding an extra `td` in the first `tr` of the `table` which spans all rows of the table and setting it to a width of `100%`. Then setting `white-space: nowrap` on the `td`'s ensures that they take up enough space to fit their contents on one line.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/vTUWj/2)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="999"></td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>longer text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
tr:first-child td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it solves my problem. Although there is no need to right align the last child. I want both columns to be together and text aligned to left. :)

Comment: Ah ok, I understood your first attempt at explaining the issue and misunderstood the second attempt :) I will roll the answer back to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `width` from `.tcl td`

```
.tcl td {
     text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about floating the first td to the right.

```
.tcl td:first-child {
     float:right;
}
```